# Writing list of basic variables to text file

Tags: python, list, file, file-writing

I want to write a text file that has some lines in the following format:

```
result: variable1 +/- error1
result: variable2 +/- error2
```

And so on... So far I have:

```
f = open('file_{a}.txt'.format(a=some_name), 'w')
for i in range(len(variable)):
    f.write('result: ', variable[i], '+/-', error[i], '\n')
```

Variable and error are floats, and some_name is a string.

But I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

I guess I need to format the `f.write` line differently but I can't figure out how. The file only needs to be read by humans, so that actual format can change.

Thanks!

Comment: `variable[i]` and/or `error[i]` are likely to be numbers rather than strings (which is what `write` is expecting you to give it. Try `f.write('result: ', str(variable[i]), '+/-', str(error[i]), '\n')`

Comment: Can you provide more info on variables `variable`, `error`, `some_name`? Seems that you're not providing a string.

Comment: Give an example of what `variable` and `error` would be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is not the type of `variable[i]` or `error[i]`,try this:

```
f = open('file_{a}.txt'.format(a=some_name), 'w')
for i in range(len(variable)):
   f.write('result: {0} +/- {1}\n'.format(variable[i],error[i]))
```

Comment: Yep that solved it, using that format is much neater

Answer (score 0):

#### From the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> **`f.write(string)`**
>
> writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written.

So you can't pass in any number of `strings` separated by `commas` as `arguments`. This is different to the way `print()` works which excepts any number of arguments and `formats` them for you...

So that is why you are getting the `error`:

> TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

**How to fix it:**

Fixing it is really easy, if you are sure `variable[i]` and `error[i]` are `strings`, you can either:

`format` them with `.format`:

```
f.write('result: {} +/- {}\n'.format(variable[i], error[i]))
```

or concatenate them with the `+` operand:

```
f.write('result: ' + variable[i] + ' +/- ' + error[i] + '\n')
```

Hope this helps!